# Were the Hufflepuff and Slytherin Quidditch teams sexist?

Tags: harry-potter, quidditch

Judging from [Harry Potter Lexicon's summary](http://www.hp-lexicon.org/quidditch/q_teams_hogwarts.html) of the Hogwarts Quidditch teams, it's clear that Quidditch is a sport that is inclusive and which both boys and girls want to play. Gryffindor in particular had Katie Bell, Angelina Johnson and Alicia Spinnet as their star trio of Chasers whilst Ginny Weasley and Demelza Robins also played for them. (Indeed, Ginny went on to play professionally.) Cho Chang was Seeker for Ravenclaw for a number of years.

Yet from the (admittedly limited) information we have about the Hufflepuff and Slytherin teams, it seems that their teams were male-only. Is it reasonable to make an argument from silence in this case?

**Is it likely that the Hufflepuff and Slytherin teams didn't allow girls to join?**

Comment: I'm actually not sure that's the case. This is a good question, though. There seem to be some female Slytherin and Hufflepuff players, but I'm not sure how canon they are.

Comment: In the video game, there are [multiple female Hufflepuff players](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Harry_Potter:_Quidditch_World_Cup) - http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Heidi_Macavoy  / http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Tamsin_Applebee

Comment: Known Slytherin players include http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Lucinda_Talkalot / http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Emma_Vanity_(Slytherin) / http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Jody_Jacknife albeit all before Harry Potter attended.

Comment: Maybe I should have clarified that I'm looking for sources from the books as first order canon or, failing that, the movies as second order canon. I'm not particularly interested in the video games etc.

Comment: Why does the lack of female players automatically presume sexism? Could it simply be that either A) none were interested at the time Harry was at Hogwarts, or B) none were good enough to make the cut?

Comment: I fail to see how having one gender only on a team makes it discrimination/sexist/whatever you wish to call it; claiming it is discrimination is simply taking it too far. And if you say an all male team is sexist then what about all female teams? Is it not sexist because it's a team of females? It's not sexist but neither is an all male team. If they are automatically excluded because of gender and it's not meant to be a team of one gender only, that's one thing. But otherwise it's not sexist in the slightest.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### The teams did indeed have female players, but they were non-canon

The mentioned female members of the Hufflepuff team were:

- Maxine O'Flaherty
- Heidi Macavoy
- Tamsin Applebee

The mentioned female members of the Slytherin team were:

- Lucinda Talkalot
- Emma Vanity
- Jody Jackknife
- Jo King (possibly)
- Winky Crocket (possibly)

None of these individuals is from book canon. They all hail either from information in the films, or from the video games.

### Some national teams seemed to have many female players

The Irish team, for example, had Moran and Mullet, which at two players out of seven is more-or-less consistent with a fair selection process.

Mullet:

> As Mullet shot toward the goal posts yet again, clutching the Quaffle
>   tightly under her arm, the Bulgarian Keeper, Zograf, flew out to meet
>   her.
>
> —*Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire*

Moran:

> Dimitrov shot straight at Moran, who had the Quaffle, nearly knocking
>   her off her broom.
>
> —*Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire*

This *is* book canon. We therefore can suppose that Quidditch is fairly equitable in general.

### So why aren't there female players on the Hufflepuff or Slytherin teams in canon?

With Hufflepuff, sufficiently few members were mentioned in canon that we cannot reach much of a conclusion about the gender makeup of their team. Specifically, we only know of:

- Cedric Diggory (whose death was a tragic accident)
- Summerby
- Zacharias Smith
- Cadwallader

A Quidditch team has seven members, and these players are present at different times, so we just don't have enough information.

With Slytherin, things are different. **We know a rather large number of their players, and they are all male.** In light of the rather severe degree of prejudice shown by many Slytherin students, this would not be particularly surprising, but the prejudice of the wizarding world is primarily against Muggles, Muggle-borns, and non-human magical creatures. Wizarding Britain, at least, had far more gender equality than its non-magical counterpart—for example, Artemisia Lufkin was elected Minister for Magic in *1798*.

Out of universe, one can speculate. Perhaps JKR saw the Slytherin team as largely interchangeable, so it was "Draco plus a bunch of random muscle-bound lackeys."

But in-universe, why would this be the case? I think even Slytherin house would not have been particularly sexist, given the prevailing attitudes of the wizarding world.

I can think of three possibilities, but they are largely speculative.

1. The Slytherin captain for most of that period, Marcus Flint, may have been particularly misogynistic himself. Thus, despite prevailing attitudes in wizarding Britain, he may have excluded female players from his team.
2. Flint may have preferred the largest players for whatever (poor) strategy he was using, which led him to select only male players.
3. Although JKR only mentioned male players, because in her view the Slytherins were generally interchangeable, we can invoke God of the Gaps and say that the players she didn't mention were female (as the films seem to have done).

Comment: Slytherin in particular were shown (in the films and books) as playing an especially *muscular* game. Presumably that would favour male players.

Comment: @Richard - Particularly if Flint were prejudiced as well. Personally, I can't think of why he didn't pick Pansy Parkinson.

Comment: @Richard, Angelina did describe Crabbe and Goyle as "the usual gorillas" before knowing anything about them in Order. Which indeed suggests men. Although, now I think on it, there are female gorillas...

Comment: @Jonah You say "poor" strategy, but hadn't Slytherin won the cup for *years* prior to Harry's arrival?

Comment: In addition to male/female members on international teams I was pretty sure the team Ginny played for - Holyhead Harpies, don't know what nationality (HP Lexicon suggests their 'home' is 'North Wales' however) - is entirely female.

Comment: @Skooba - I suspect there was a lot of cheating involved. The Slytherin players aren’t portrayed as very good at Quidditch, but we *do* see them cheating a lot. As for the merit of the strategy, selecting only male players rather than the best players would *a priori* be a bad idea, but it would seem particularly bad in Quidditch, where height and muscle mass are a disadvantage for the positions of Seeker and Chaser.